# CompressionQuality for Plugin.Media doesn't work on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using `Plugin.Media` and it's `CompressionQuality` property to compress my image in terms of size, but it doesn't compress.

Following is the code snippet:

```
if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
{
    var photo0 = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        SaveToAlbum = true,
        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Small,
        DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
        CompressionQuality = 90            
    });
}
```

I am trying the same on iOS device. Can someone help? I am using `Plugin.Media 4.0.1.1`

Comment: How did you conclude it doesnt work?

Comment: hi @GeraldVersluis , while writing this question I was checking the image size of the pictures saved in the album, which I think is not correct !! It creates another copy in the app folder which we cant access.

Since I cannot access the files stored I am just thinking if I can access those files and check the size. I am now just checking the time to upload the pictures , which is almost same with and without CompressionQuality

Comment: OK, let me rephrase; what do you expect `CompressionQuality` to do? The name might be a bit misleading. The value without compression is 100, so 90 is just a little bit of compression. If you set it lower, the image will be smaller, but also the quality will go down. Try setting it to 10 and see what it does with the size.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis That worked ! I just didn't read the instructions properly ! Thanx !

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a matter of perception. What do you expect `CompressionQuality` to do? The name might be a bit misleading, I agree.

The value without compression is 100, so 90 is just a little bit of compression. If you set it lower, the image will be smaller, but also the quality will go down. Try setting it to 10 and see what it does with the size. It is similar (or probably exactly the same) as the compression on JPEGs that work the same way.